# Extract other columns with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a product.csv which has 6 columns and I need to groupby `customer_id` and `product_id` and do a count. When I group by, the other 4 columns drop, is there any ways to groupby and retain all/specific columns?

`product.csv`:-

```
product_id,price,customer_id,date_of_purchase,points,product_category
P54,1046,C113,24/07/2021 19:50,5,garden_furniture
P45,380,C113,23/08/2021 19:50,5,garden_furniture
P43,1793,C113,02/02/2021 19:50,5,garden_furniture
P45,380,C113,23/08/2021 19:50,5,garden_furniture
```

What I have tried;

```
import pandas as pd


product_df = pd.read_csv('product.csv')
product_df = product_df.groupby(['customer_id','product_id']).size().reset_index(name='count')
product_df
```

This is my expected output;

| customer_id | product_id | points | product_category | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C113 | P54 | 5 | garden_furniture | 1 |
| C113 | P45 | 5 | garden_furniture | 2 |
| C113 | P43 | 5 | garden_furniture | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

When you want to keep the same size as the dataframe in a groupby, use `transform`:

```
    df.assign(count = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'product_id']).points.transform('size'))

  product_id  price customer_id  date_of_purchase  points  product_category  count
0        P54   1046        C113  24/07/2021 19:50       5  garden_furniture      1
1        P45    380        C113  23/08/2021 19:50       5  garden_furniture      2
2        P43   1793        C113  02/02/2021 19:50       5  garden_furniture      1
3        P45    380        C113  23/08/2021 19:50       5  garden_furniture      2
```

You can drop columns you don't want with the `drop` method:

```
df.assign(count = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'product_id']).points.transform('size')).drop(columns='date_of_purchase')

  product_id  price customer_id  points  product_category  count
0        P54   1046        C113       5  garden_furniture      1
1        P45    380        C113       5  garden_furniture      2
2        P43   1793        C113       5  garden_furniture      1
3        P45    380        C113       5  garden_furniture      2
```

Comment: Apologies, I have added the another product to get the count 2. Can I ask what is `.points`?

Comment: you have a `points` column - in pandas, depending on the column name, you can access it via brackets ``['points']`` or as an attribute ``.points``

Comment: Ok, is there a way we can exclude `date_of_purchase ` column?

Comment: Can I know is there a way to select and display only some columns, in this case I want to exclude `date_of_purchase `?

Comment: Yes `drop` method works, my concern is getting `product_id` `P45 `in a single row. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, just add a boolean filter: ``df.query('product_id == "P45"')``. ``df`` in this case is the result of your transform. Have a look at pandas docs for indexing and selecting data

Comment: I have multiple rows similar to `P45`, is there any thing I can do to this ```product_df.groupby(['customer_id','product_id']).size().reset_index(name='count')```, to get other columns `price`, `points` and `product_category `?